# File size difference between MB and bytes

Tags: c#, fileinfo

I'm trying to understand the following issue. I am reading the file info for a file as follows:

```
FileInfo info = new FileInfo(path);
```

The code then returns **16599774** bytes for my file when I do `info.Length`. When I convert the **bytes** to **MB**, I get **15.8 MB**.

Can someone explain the difference between the size in bytes as opposed to MB to me please?

Comment: 1 [MiB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mebibyte) = 1 048 576 bytes, much like, but not equal to, 1 million bytes.

Answer (score 8):

Usually, file systems compute file sizes in [mebibytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mebibyte) (MiB), but report results as [megabytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megabyte) (MB). The difference between these units is that MB is a base 10 unit, which has 1000000 bytes (one million) as you expected. But MiB is a base 2 unit, which contains 1024*1024 bytes (1048576 bytes). If you'll divide 16599774 bytes by 1048576 (bytes per mebibyte) you will get 15.8 mebibytes (MiB). But again, OS reports this number as megabytes (MB).

Note that usually HDD manufacturers use this base10/base2 trick and report disc sizes in gigabytes (GB) or terabytes (TB). And you see exactly same size 'reduction' when you check HDD size in file system. E.g. 5TB is actually 4.5 tebibytes TiB. But file system will show you 4.5 TB.

Comment: From a technical standpoint, a megabyte is in base 10; a mebibyte is in base 2.  So a megabyte is exactly 1,000,000 bytes and a mebibyte is 1,048,576 bytes.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mebibyte

Comment: @NickLarsen Although technically correct this adds just confusion, most systems I know of use MB just as 1024*1024 bytes. Even windows explorer does. Not sure if any system actually prints out MIB or KIB or whatever.

Comment: I know it's confusing however it comes up in so many common scenarios, like buying a hard drive or new iPhone where you are buying in base 10, that I think it's an import distinction.

Comment: @HimBromBeere: some file manages for Linux do indeed use MiB explicitly, but more out of geekiness than anything else. Aside from that, however, context is everything -- a network transfer of 1 kilobyte/sec really is 1000 bytes/sec, not 1024, and no network engineer will be convinced by a developer that that goes against "most systems they know of". They will argue, and rightfully so, that developers are the minority when it comes to abusing [standardized prefixes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix). That horse has bolted a long time ago, the confusion was always there.

Comment: They should start to use `MiB` everywhere to not confuse us. I did not even know the unit `MiB` after decades working with computers. I always wondered why some use `/1024` and some use `/1000`. For my own projects I stick with MB, i. e. 1 MB = 1000 kB = 1000000 B.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are thinking it is exactly 1 million bytes, but it is actually 1 Megabyte = 1,048,576 Bytes

Comment: According to the other answers, this is wrong. Correct is: 1 Megabyte = 1,000,000 Bytes. See above.

Answer (score 0):

The Mebibyte is a multiple of the unit byte for quantities of digital information.

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mebibyte) is the Wikipedia page on it.

A Mebibyte is 2^20 bytes, or 1,048,576 bytes. You're not converting to Megabytes, but to Mebibytes.

The number of bytes (16,599,774) divided by bytes/MiB (1,048,576) = 15.8308 MiB.